# Admin template is ignored when deploying

Tags: django-templates, django-admin, django-staticfiles, django-deployment

I have a strange situation here using Django 3.2.8:

When deploying, **only one** admin template is being ignored (but not if `debug == True`):

This is my directory after deploying (and before, they are identical):

[image]

change_form.html is applied correctly, whilst submit_line.html is not when `debug = false`.

content of change_form.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block inline_field_sets %}
    {% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
        {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
    {% endfor %}
    <h3>
        <p>WARNING!</p> 
    </h3>
{% endblock %}
```

content of submit_line.html:

```
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

<div class="submit-row">
    {% if show_save %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}
    {% if show_delete_link %}
        {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
        <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if show_download_zip %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'zip' %}" name="_download_zip" />
    {% endif %}
    {% if show_save_as_new %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" />
    {% endif %}
    {% if show_save_and_add_another %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />
    {% endif %}
    {% if show_save_and_continue %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" />
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

pre-deployment, with `debug = True`:
[image]
compares to:
[image]

**Edit**:

A little further digging:

When moving the logic from `submit_line.html` to `change_form.html` I get my download button, but **only after setting all the buttons visibility by hand** - again, this only happens when `DEBUG == False`:

working `render_change_form` from `admin.py` code fragment:

```
def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
    context.update({'show_save_and_add_another': True})
    context.update({'show_save_and_continue': True})
    context.update({'show_save': True})
    context.update({'show_delete_link': True})        
    if not context["original"] == None:
        context.update({'show_download_zip': True})

    return super().render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

working `change_form.html`:

```
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    {% load i18n admin_urls %}

    <div class="submit-row">
        {% if show_save %}
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}
        {% if show_delete_link %}
            {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
            <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
        {% endif %}
        {% if show_download_zip %}
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'zip' %}" name="_download_zip" />
        {% endif %}
        {% if show_save_as_new %}
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" />
        {% endif %}
        {% if show_save_and_add_another %}
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />
        {% endif %}
        {% if show_save_and_continue %}
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" />
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When doing the same in `DEBUG == True`, the `context.update()`'s are not needed, also django uses the correct `submit_line.html` template without any issues.

So ... now I know how to fix this, but I can't figure out why this is happening the way I observed it.